# How to make a Web Service be use multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, service, web

I have a simple java web service.  I want to have the web service be threaded, where each call to a web method gets its own thread to do processing. The processing takes a long time and I don't want it to block, prevent other calls to the web method from happening. Instead, I want the web method to only create the Threads and for the Thread itself to respond/return a value to the client after its done processing. Is that possible?

EDIT:

Here's a semi-pseudocode of what I have right now:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface="Service")
public class ServiceImpl {

    public ServiceImpl() 
    {
        // Initialization
    }

    public String GetResult(input)
    {
        // Does long processing

        return Result;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is instead of GetResult() doing the long processing, I want it only spawn the Runnable that will do the long processing and have GetResult() return and ready to service another request. I also want the Runnable to respond to the waiting client.

EDIT 2:

I just realized that I'm asking a silly question. I'm fairly new to implement WS's. I had thought that WS's only took one request at a time sequentially. I didn't know each request is already automatically threaded.

Comment: It is possible.  What have you tried.  What searches have you done.  What code have you looked at?  Please edit your question and provide more details.

Comment: What kind of client do you have? Server-side? command-line/ batch? GUI? Swing? JavaFX?

Comment: It looks like you are really asking for the WS to be asynchronous... That is also possible.

Comment: @vkraemer Yes, that is what I would like. How do you make the WS run asynchronously so its is not stuck on one method call.

Comment: Regarding edit 2... You will need to make sure that the code for your service is thread-safe to take advantage of the requests being automatically threaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use JMS for asynchronous calls. That's the best way.

You could also fire up a thread, and manage them yourself.  That's not generally recommended.  Good management of the thread pool, and keeping track of which threads might be taking to long requires a lot of overhead code.

Comment: I'm not looking for an asynchronous call as I don't care if the client is suspended while waiting for the response (I even extended the timeout). I'm more concerned about the WS only being able to service one client at a time since the processing time is fairly long (~10 min).